# Inject a value at the front based on count of query that's run after

Tags: t-sql

I want to inject a conditional value.

```
Select 'Select a Value' as CarID, 
       'Select a Value' as CarName
UNION
Select Distinct CarID, 
       CarName 
from Cars c
where ..some condition...
```

So here I only want to inject the "Select a value" if the select statement returns a count of > 1 because this is gonna be the data set for a dropdown list.

so in other words I do not want to include this union if that select returns 0 or 1 results.

Is there a way to kinda go backwards or check the count of that to inject or not inject that in the beginning of the returned list?

Answer (score 3):

```
with C as 
(
  select CarID, CarName
  from Cars
  --where ..some condition...
)
select CarID, CarName
from
  (
    select CarID, CarName, 1 as Sort
    from C
    union all
    select 'Select a Value', 'Select a Value',  0
    where exists(select * from C)
  ) T
order by Sort
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7ba6/1)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server,

```
SELECT * FROM (
    Select 'Select a Value' as CarID, 
           'Select a Value' as CarName
    UNION
    Select CarID, CarName 
    from Cars c
    -- WHERE...
) SUB
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT>1
```